# Import Coordinates from string (In C)

Tags: c

I'm writing a code (In C) that reads string input from the user.
I need to recognize a command, followed by coordinate paramters, in the following form:

> `Move <1,a> to <2,b>[<3,c><4,d>...]`

How can I read and seperate properly the coordinates in the given string?
(Each coordinate is composed of an integer and an alphabet letter.)

Thanks.

Edit:
To clarify, I have the input already in a string, and I recognized the command ' Move'.
I'm looking for a simple way to turn the list of the paramters given to a coordinate (Which contains two integers).

Comment: Humm.. read the line with `fgets()` and then parse it with `sscanf()`?

Comment: This is not a "do my job/homework site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the constant strings as parameters to `scanf`, like

```
sscanf(str, "Move <%d,%c> to <%d,%c>", &n1, &c1, &n2, &c2);
```

Be sure to check the return value of `sscanf`. It will return the number of successfully read variables (4 in this case).

This will only work if the format is exactly like that. For a more robust version, you could do something like:

```
sscanf(str, "[^<]%d[^,]%c[^>][^<]%d[^,]%c[^>]", &n1, &c1, &n2, &c2);
```

This will also successfully read things like:

> Mooooveeee   <  1,   a> somewhere <2,b>